# Which has better career prospects : PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am a Senior Oracle DBA. At the moment , my DBA career is not affected by the rise of open source databases.
But, It might not stay like this for long.
To make my career future proof, which open source database should I learn? PostgreSQL or MySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly PostgreSQL.

Its not because db-engines ranked its the [DBMS of the year 2018](https://db-engines.com/en/blog_post/79) 
we have many more reasons that PostgreSQL is the best among PostgreSQL and MySQL.

I will give you two reasons why I think learning  PostgreSQL is good option

1. [Amazon moving off their databases](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/08/01/amazon-plans-to-move-off-oracle-software-by-early-2020.html) from Oracle to Amazon Aurora which is based on PostgreSQL mostly.
2. Microsoft acquiring CITUS DATA and investing alot in their cloud services with PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL

According to DB-Rankings.com, year over end,

- PostgreSQL is up +85.18
- MySQL is down **the exact same amount 85.18**

MySQL is still twice as big, but the trend is pretty pronounced.

Source: https://db-engines.com/en/ranking

---

> I am a Senior Oracle DBA.

As an Oracle DBA, you probably have high standards. All the more reason to not use trash.

Comment: Where is the +/- 85.18 in that link?